# Diameter of an 11' foot high, 3" (2&7/8) steel post footer hole

Tags: concrete, post, hole, measuring

I know that the general standard for post footers is to make the diameter of the footer hole 3 times wider than the post itself. However, I want to make sure that even in an 11' foot post (which seems kind of high to me), that this rule is still ok. Or should the footer hole be a bit wider for such a high post? The questions regards the corner post of an 11' foot high chainlink fence. Thanks in advance!

Comment: the post must surely be more than 11 feet if the fence is 11 feet high

Answer (score 0):

I have always gone down minimum 1/3 of what you have above ground. Diameter off twice the post the top 6" opening out to 4 times the diameter.if your post is not long enough to give you the minimum amount below ground weld or bolt something to extend it

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Your first sentence doesn't answer the original question; the second sentence is very confusing, and the third sentence seems dubious. Would you edit to clarify? Thanks.